# postgres: delete before insert requires lock?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, locking

I want to replace a list of records for a client. It seems that postgres does not have a `merge`statement that handles my case I decided to do it as follows:

I delete all records of a client like so

`DELETE FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_TABLE.CLIENT_ID=?`

and then insert some new records:

`INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (CLIENT_ID, ...) VALUES (1, ...), (2, ...)`

I'm doing that in a transaction.

My question: I know about write-after-read problems that require a form of synchronization (locks, or a certain level of transaction isolation).

Is these one of these cases?

Comment: The equivalent of a MERGE in Postgres is `insert ... on conflict (..) do update`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your reply. That is not quiet the same use case since it does not 'replace' a list of records. It would leave records not included in the insert statement.

Comment: Can you give some rough numbers / percentages? To do it in place, how many rows have to be removed, how many updated, how many inserted? What kind of concurrent access can happen during the operation? And is there a separate `client` table?

Comment: @Ynv: you can still delete those in a second step: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=108acdb10cffc53eb6f8575955658146

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have too many clients, you could partition the table by `client_id`.

Then replacing the data for a client could be as fast as it gets:

```
BEGIN;
TRUNCATE some_table_partition_1;
COPY some_table_partition_1 (client_id, ...) FROM STDIN
   (FORMAT 'csv', FREEZE);
COMMIT;
```

The partition will automatically be locked for the duration of the operation.

Comment: How much is "too many clients" ? 10, 1000, 1000000 ?

Comment: For PostgreSQL v12, I would put the limit at a few thousand.